# jquery fade in navigation fading in and out repeatedly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fadein

I have a navigation set up to fade in and out based on scrollTop. The problem is, is that it is rapidly blinking, never fades in or out completely.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="drop-nav">
    <ul>
        <li class="drop-nav-logo"><img style="width: 97px;" src=""></li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Solutions</li>
        <li>Products</li>
        <li>Support</li>
        <li>Blog</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="demo-us">Request Free Demo</div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
//Drop nav
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).width() > 667) {
        if($(this).scrollTop() < 400) {
            $('.drop-nav').fadeOut();
        }
        else {
            $('.drop-nav').fadeIn();
        }
    }
});
```

How do I get it to fade in and out appropriately?

Answer (score 1):

You can call `.stop()` before the fade in/out:

```
if($(this).scrollTop()<400){
   $('.drop-nav').stop().fadeOut();
}else{
   $('.drop-nav').stop().fadeIn();
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ujuttzmd/)

From the [**documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/stop/):

`When .stop() is called on an element, the currently-running animation (if any) is immediately stopped.`

Comment: How can I get it so that it starts faded out?